# Windows 10 BSOD on boot PNP_DETECTED_FATAL_ERROR and recovery with ubuntu livecd

Tags: linux, windows-10, data-recovery, bsod

I've got this Dell XPS laptop with Win10 installed, which fails to boot with BSOD "PNP_DETECTED_FATAL_ERROR" before login screen. From what I gather it happend after some update in May.

It cannot be recovered with Microsoft's recovery tools, but I know there are some files my client would like to have saved. Laptop is setup with secure boot and UEFI.

Now here's the wierd part. When I boot it up with my Ubuntu 20 LTS live usb it mounts system partition properly, but

- ./Users has no actual profiles, only Default and Guest
- when listing directories most filesizes are unknown and seen as '?' with ls -al
- gparted reports that windows partition has only 10GB in use (in total that's a 120GB M2 ssd, impossible for a system that's been in use for few years)
- Whole directory seems... barren and default

Is it possible that Microsoft has some countermeasures that prevent live usb users from even browsing system partition? Or could an update mess up things that badly?

For the record, windows.old has some files, that i can't restore as they also are of unknown size and cli reports them as non-existent.

EDIT: The partition is not encrypted, and even if it were I should be able to access it, no?

Answer (score 0):

I think your windows partition is corrupted, because a lot of files cannot be recognized. Linux Plays well with NTFS partitions and can read and write them. So I advice you to perform a clean re-installation of windows. Create a new bootable disk image, backup all files and then re-install.

And as an answer to your another question, you can prevent live USBs from accessing windows or any other logical drives by setting up device encryption or by using BitLocker. More on device encryption technologies by Microsoft here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028713/windows-10-turn-on-device-encryption